# How does spark handle missing values?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Apache spark support sparse data.

For example, we can use `MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(...)` to load data into an `RDD`.

I was wondering how does `spark` deal with those `missing values`.

Comment: My mllib-fu is weak, so I'll leave this as a comment, but if I recall, they build out a dictionary of values that ARE listed and simply do not store empty data. This way anything can be extrapolated based on that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark creates an RDD of Labeled points, and each labeled point has a label and a vector of features. Note that this is a Spark Vector which does support sparse elements (currently Sparse vectors are represented by an array of non-indices and a second array of doubles for each of the non-null value).

Comment: Thanks. I guess RDD 's job is to represent the data. if we use it for data mining, it is the training routine 's job to handle those missing value.